# TimeSpan and DispatchTimer

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm using a class to modify a DateTime and using a TimeSpan to display X hours, Y minutes, Z seconds to a WPF label every second with a DispatchTimer. The code itself gives the proper timespan, however the DispatchTimer is giving the wrong output. Can I get some input on what is going on here?

The ModifiedTime Minutes properties is still being queried during debug breaks (hovering over ModifiedTime.Minutes keeps giving an increasing number.), is this the norm?

Runtime output starts at 3 minutes, then displays 8 minutes, 13, 18, 23, 28, etc.

Library:

```
public Clock() {
  load_ = DateTime.Now;
  time_ = new DateTime();
  time_ = DateTime.Now;
  modifiedTime_ = new DateTime();         
  modifiedTime_ = DateTime.Now;
  difference = TimeSpan.Zero;
}

public TimeSpan ModifiedTime {
  //Convert the real time to timespan.
  //display X Years, Y Days, Z Hours...
  get {
  modifiedTime_ = modifiedTime_.AddMinutes(1.0);
  difference = modifiedTime_.Subtract(time_);
  return difference;
  }
  set { difference = value; }
}
```

WPF:

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer; 
public MainWindow() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
  dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
  dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
  dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  lblModTime.Content = clock.ModifiedTime.Hours + " hours, " + clock.ModifiedTime.Minutes + " minutes, " + clock.ModifiedTime.Seconds + " seconds, " + clock.ModifiedTime.Milliseconds + " milliseconds.";
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Basically, I'm comparing two dates. One is the tme the program was loaded, and the second will be incrementing by some arbitrary amount of time every second. I'm trying to display the span between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, every time you call clock.ModifiedTime. in your dispatcher (4 times!) you add a minute to the modified time, plus possibly once more for evaluating the statement in the debugger.  That would explain your incrementing your display by 5 each time.

Comment: This was the problem, all I actually needed to do was catch the ModifiedTime in the WPF with one call to a timespan object. That is, make TimeSpan x = clock.ModifiedTime in the WPF before calling x.Minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add one minute to the time started for every second that passed. So take the difference in seconds, then add that as minutes to time started for your new time.

```
public TimeSpan ModifiedTime
{
    get
    {
        TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now - TimeStarted;
        return TimeStarted.AddMinutes(elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```